# How to Display DataTables in a View when using ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, gridview, datatable

I have an Action as below which returns a dataset to a partial view:

```
public ActionResult DataSet(int id)
{

DataSet dataSet = Model.CreateDataSet(id);

return PartialView(dataSet);

}
```

and I'm using it like this in my main view:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("DataSet", new {id= 1});}
```

I'd like to show the contents of the DataSet on my Razor Partial View. For example, if my dataset has 2 datatables, I'd like to display 2 Grid Tables with the columns and rows.

I realized that MVC doesn't have any GridView control like WebForms.

How would that be possible in MVC?

Thanks

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Displaying-DataTables-in-Asp-Net-MVC-Razor-Page

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, use a premade grid (the one in MVCContrib is really good and what i use) or manually format the table yourself (nested foreaches will do this just fine)

Also using either of these methods there's no real need to pull the table out into a separate view (unless you have other reasons for it)

Comment: The MVCContrib: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&referringTitle=Documentation what's the syntax to create the Grid for a DataTable? DataTable has Columns property and Rows property.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation, http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid&referringTitle=Documentation what you probably want is something like Html.Grid(dataTable.Rows).Columns(c=> {some column definitions})